# Is there a way for console.log() to update a line instead of appending new ones?

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

If I want to track a variable that updates very frequently, I can do `console.log(myVar);`, which appends a line at the bottom of the console:

[image]

Is there a way to **replace** the value of the last line, instead of **appending** a new line at the bottom?

[image]

This would be super helpful, because then I could look at previous logs without having them get scrolled out of view at the top.

I've tried the following:

```
console.clear();
console.log(myObject);
console.log(myVar);
```

But this doesn't work because re-logging objects collapses them, plus it flickers too much in Chrome. I read the [MDN documentation on the console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console), and even though it has lots of neat features, I couldn't figure out how to just rewrite a single line. I've seen it being done in terminals/command prompts, does the browser console have that capability?

Comment: Not sure what your question is despite enough detail but are you looking for `console.log(myObject, myVar);` as a single liner which will probably tell you state of Object along with millis on the same line? OR you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject), myVar);`

Comment: I don't think it is possible to update individual lines of output in the console. Like you said: there is nothing in the any of the documentation that suggests this can be done. If you really want to accomplish something like this, I think you'll need to do it outside of the console (for example, output the value to the page instead)

Comment: @Rikin I updated my question to be more concise. What I want to do is I want to rewrite the last line in the console, instead of appending a new one. I need to keep previous logs visible, and appending a new line quickly pushes old logs out of view.

Comment: @Marquizzo apparently .clear would be the only thing that you can do (I think) but since you want only last line output in console, you may try wrapping your `console.log` statement in some `setTimeout` and cleartimeout if new statement is pushed which will cancel out previous callback. That way you are only pushing last statement to console but at a delayed time.

Comment: It is gamedev practice to simply append a div to the page body with fixed position and update its HTML ...but not in the console.

Comment: @Martin Yeah, I ended up having to build my own console in the DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google chrome has now in console ability to "Create live expression"

[image]

Comment: Nice! That's a really helpful alternative to creating `console.logs()`. Looks like it's been available since [Chrome 70](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/08/devtools#watch). Worth noting that live expression values update every 250 milliseconds.

Comment: is there a way to create a live expression programmatically?

Comment: @gotjosh I found that the best method to track a single value is to display it in an HTMLElement, like a <div> In the corner, then update it via JavaScript.